# How to measure a cup of "solid" ingredient?

Tags: measurements, conversion

I was reading a recipe in which it was mentioned among the ingredients "8 cups of broccoli florets". Measuring by "cups" is for liquids, right? For solid ingredients, are we measuring the "weight" of the ingredient?

How to convert "8 cups of broccoli florets" into kilograms/grams?

Comment: Good question although I suspect there is no single answer given the  number of different ways you might choose to trim the broccoli (long stem, large florets or short stem, small florets).

Comment: While you can fill a cup with broccoli, it does seem a strange tactic given all the spaces there will be between the pieces, the result will vary wildly depending on the type and trim, as Chris says. It's questions like this that make me wonder why some people use cups at all...

Comment: @Steve: Simple: Americans do not own scales.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's asking for exactly what it says: 8 cups of broccoli. Measuring by volume is certainly best-defined for liquids, but it works fine for solids too. It works best if you have a large measuring bowl - or just a bowl that you happen to know is around 8 cups (two quarts, about two liters). Or you can just guess by eye, knowing how much volume that is. A recipe with broccoli isn't going to fail if you're off by a bit.

(If you really prefer weight, this [nutrition data](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/vegetables-and-vegetable-products/2356/2) says a cup chopped is 91 grams, so 8 cups might be a bit over 700 grams.)

Comment: http://www.onlineconversion.com/weight_volume_cooking.htm works great too.